# Проверка выборки на соответствие распределению

Tags: математика, matlab, статистика

У меня есть выборка. В Excel я построила гистограмму данной выборки. Наглядно оценила, что полученную гистограмму можно аппроксимировать гамма-распределением. Затем рассчитала параметры гамма-распределения для моей выборки: альфа и гамму, построила функцию плотности гамма-распределения и сопоставила на одном графике мою гистограмму и функцию плотности. Визуально я оценила, что моя выборка соответствует этому гамма-распределения. Данную гипотезу я решила проверить с помощью Matlab и функции `kstest`. Я написала следующий код:

```
y1 = load('data.txt');
phat = gamfit(y1);
y1min = min(y1)-1;
y1max = max(y1)+1;
x=y1min:1:y1max;
y2=gamcdf (x,phat(1),phat(2));
cdf=[x' y2'];
H = kstest(y1,cdf,0.9)
```

На выходе `H` равно 1, то есть гипотезу о соответствии распределений мы отклоняем.  Даже при изменении критического уровня значимости `H = 1`.

Правильно ли я написала код для проверки гипотезы о соответствии моей выборки гамма-распределению? Потому что ответ меня не очень то устраивает, потому что визуально графики распределений похожи.[image: Гистограмма выборки и гамма-распределение]

Answer (score 1):

1. Расчет параметров Гамма-Распределения в Matlab  выполняется функцией  gamfit. Вы же использовали функцию raylfit, которая выполняет расчет параметров распределения Релея. Что в общем-то не одно и тоже. Более того, у функции Релея определяется один параметр.
2. Предыдущее не противоречит тому факту, что согласно критерию Колмогорова-Смирнова  ваши данные не подчиняются теоретическая закону распределения  (в данном случае - Релея) с заданными вами параметрами. Что-бы убедиться в этом, попробуйте применить другой тест согласия.
3. Хотя по рисунку весьма трудно сказать, какой-же там в действительности закон распределения, все-таки ваши данные действительно больше похожи на гамма-распределение, чем на распределение Релея. Так что еще не все потеряно :-)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Вопрос на форум писала вчера вечером, что-то глаз зымылился - перепутала часть кода. Вместо проверки на соответствие гамма-распределению вставила код на соответствие распределению Рэлея. Внесла изменения в вопрос. А какие в матлабе еще можно применить критерии согласия? Там же только kstest реализован и также проверка выборки на нормальность и всё.

Comment: Так на рисунке осталось то-же распределение Релея. (Оранжевая кривая). Это раз.

Comment: . Помимо критерия К-С существует еще и хи-квадрат критерий, критерий Барнета, критерий Джини, Крамера-Мизеса, Андерсона-Дарлинга, Купера, Катценбайсаре-Хакля и др. Некоторые из функций реализованы и размещены на https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/. Некоторые нетрудно написать самому. Ну и на MatLab свет клином не сошелся. Есть Pythоn, есть R. Даже на EXCEL есть (или можно написать самому) соответствующие процедуры. Это два.

Comment: И откуда уверенность, что у вас именно Гамма-распределение? Посмотрите тут - http://iglin.exponenta.ru/All/Book2Disc/AllDocs/Part11/part11.html Там есть пример подбора наиболее подходящего распределения из заданного набора. Возможно, это вам поможет. Это три.

Comment: спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Спасибо на данном ресурсе выражается путем нажатия поддержки/принятия ответа. Но тем не менее - был рад помочь. Будут вопросы - пишите.